# How do I resolve Autodiscover for Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007

I'm a little confused with autodiscovery. I have autodisovery.domain.com as a secondary name in my SSL. i have an A record setup for"autodiscovery" on my ISP DNS which points to my email server. However I do not have any SRV records internally...
What other steps do I need to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/04/30/438249.aspx) article, its probably one of the best I've seen for setting up Autodiscover. (not autodiscovery) It should hopefully get you pointed in the right direction.

Also, what type of cert did you get? Was it a UC?

Comment: I got the recommended cert from Godaddy. Multi domain. Looks like a good article. I think I need to wait for the A record to provision before I get ahead of myself...

Comment: Wait for the A record to provision? What do you mean? If you created an A record it should be available immediately.

Comment: ...good catch though, I had the DNS record as autodiscovery...

Comment: DNS with the ISP...do I not need that?

Comment: Sounds like it may just be a DNS name issue, outlook is hardwired to look for specific addresses.

Comment: Well just to be clear, my cert includes my mail.domain.com and autodiscover.domain.com as a secondary address. As well, my DNS records are set for both of those addresses to point to my mail server...

Comment: As a follow up, adding the autodiscover to my ISP DNS now resolves the autodiscover testing. Thanks Dan